# Change table's column name using stored procedure in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, alter

I'm new to Oracle PL/SQL. I got a table name `EMP_1812057(SAL, HIRDATE)`. How to change its column's names by creating a stored procedure? Can i do something like passing new name as a parameter of the procedure and then it will change the column name to that new name? Can you give me some examples, please? Thanks anyway.

Comment: If this is to learn about passing values and using them to create dynamic sql, then fine.  If this is to address a real business issue, then I'd say your data model is seriously, fatally flawed,  It should _NOT_ be necessary to change column names such that you'd need a parameter driven procedure to do it.  And even your table name, with that '1812057' element, is strongly suggestive of further flaws in the data model, including what is actually _data_ in the table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what would be that procedure's real purpose (we don't modify column names that frequently, and we rarely do it in a procedure), but - you'd use dynamic SQL with appropriate `ALTER TABLE` statement.

For example, rename `SAL` column to `SALARY`:

```
SQL> desc emp_1812057
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 SAL                                                NUMBER
 HIREDATE                                           DATE

SQL> create or replace procedure p_emp is
  2  begin
  3    execute immediate 'alter table emp_1812057 rename column sal to salary';
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_emp

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> desc emp_1812057
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 SALARY                                             NUMBER
 HIREDATE                                           DATE

SQL>
```

Comment: The point of my question is, if you pass a new name to the procedure, it will change old name of the column to that new name.

Comment: OK; pass the name as procedure's parameter. Concatenate it to the resto of the ALTER TABLE statement. Beware of SQL injection (read on DBMS_ASSERT).